# Dash doesn't recognize that application is installed

Tags: unity, 12.10, software-center, unity-dash, geary

I've installed **Geary** from the software center, but I can't launch it from the Dash nor did I manage to create an app icon on the Launcher. The Software center has no problem seeing that the app is installed (see screenshot)

[image]

Running the command "geary" ***will*** launch the app.

Is there any way I can force the Dash to function properly?

Thanks,
Calixte

*PS: Does anyone know what this problem is related to? I tried re-installing the app and restarting the computer but that has no effect at all. I have practically installed nothing on this computer, so I can't imagine what app could interfere with the Dash*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with the Dash.  Rather, it's a [known issue with Geary 0.2.1.](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/5968)

Answer (score 0):

The search results in the dash indicate that the application is not installed. This could be a bug in Unity or one of its components, so you should file a bug about it by running `ubuntu-bug unity`.

I just tried to install geary to test this and the dash worked fine to launch the application, and it did appear in the launcher. I was unable to actually configure geary though, so it was not usable.

You can try to log out of Unity, wait a few seconds, then log back in. It should work ok then. If the dash still isn't showing it correctly after that, then the bug could run a bit deeper than Unity. But this would be good information to include in the bug report, along with the screenshot you attached here.

Comment: Restarting unity doesn't work. I'll file in the bug report when I have time.
Thanks :)